# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'TM_COEFF'

Tags: python, image, opencv, templates

My code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

template = cv2.imread('Snaps\\full_snap__1511789636.png', 0)
img_bgr = cv2.imread('DICE\\1.png')
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_bgr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
w, h = template.shape[::-1]
res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_gray, template, cv2.TM_COEFF)
threshhold = 0.8
loc = np.where(res >= threshhold)

for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
    cv2.rectangle(img_rgb, pt, (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h), (0,255,255), 2)

cv2.imshow('Detected',img_rgb)
```

I installed `cv2` properly, but now I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'TM_COEFF'
```

What could be the source of that error?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. 
Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named 
["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). 
And more importantly, please read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). 
You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Are you talking about template matching? Except that you just want to know if it found the template (not the location etc)? Please clarify.

Comment: Yes that is true, knowing location would be good as well(maybe storing it in a different variable), but I just do not want to circle it or anything. I just need to know if one image is contained within another one.

Comment: **voting to close due to a typo**. you're missing a C: `TM_CCOEFF`